# Installation crashes. SQL Server 2008 r2 Express

Tags: sql-server, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 express on my fresh win 7 ultimate x64 install. Every time the installation starts, it crashes with the following message:

```
Description:

Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: setup100.exe
Application Version: 10.50.1600.1
Application Timestamp: 4bb6742c
Fault Module Name: mscorwks.dll
Fault Module Version: 2.0.50727.4952
Fault Module Timestamp: 4bebe78c
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 00000000001e41a0
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID: 1033
```

Did anyone had similar problem? how did you solve?

Comment: I seem to remember seeing something about installation problems when the UI did not have focus somewhere on SO...

Comment: @Martin, I recall that too - I think it's hit me, but I can't for the life of me remember the details :/

Comment: I binged whole 300 billion web pages but couldn't find nothing. :-(

Answer (score 1):

So here are some ideas to try if they help. First, I assume that you're installing the 64bit version of SQL Express? Also, the faulting module is a .NET component, so maybe try repairing .NET 2.0? Finally, I'm not sure this would work, but as a last-ditch effort, you could reboot to safe mode and try the installation from there. I know these are just shots-in-the-dark, but if 300 billion web pages don't have the answer, then maybe some random tests might get lucky.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I don't want to experiment on it anymore. When installation crashed when it was half finished, I had a hard time uninstalling partially installed sql server. uninstaller also crashed, I tried 99 times and last one did the trick. I'll try to install the one which is contained in VS installation package, maybe it will help. anyway thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0):

In my experience SQL express installs tend to crash (well over the past 5 years anyway) when you install direct from the web. I would allways recommend downloading the complete install package, then runing it from a local folder. Everytime the direct web install has crashed for me (probably around a dozen time now accross various versions), downloading the full install and then running it locally has lead to a clean install.